# constant high frequency beep when headphones are plugged into headphone jack?

Tags: laptop, audio, headphone-jack

I have a problem with my laptop.
It has Win 10(64bit) with Realtek High Definition Audio.

Whenever I plug my headphones into the headphone jack, I hear a constant high frequency beep on the right headphone. It's not loud but annoying.
Even if I mute everything, disable microphone input, unplug all usb etc, I can still hear it.
With cheap headphones, I can't hear the beep( mostly because the high frequency is only noticable with quality headphones).

I tried uninstalling the driver and reinstall it, but I keep hearing the beep.

But I've found a little solution: When I go to the volume mixer, and press on the system sound bar and the typical windows sound appear, and plug the headphones while the sound is still playing, then I don't hear the high frequency beep anymore as long as the system is not off.
Even when I unplug and plug the headphones , there is no beep.
But when I unplug the headphone, wait some seconds and then plug them again, the beep appears again.

I really want to fix this problem so I don't want to depend on that trick.
What could be the cause of this beep?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you didn't have this problem before you had Windows 10—and you upgraded from an earlier version of Windows—it is likely that your sound card drivers are somehow causing this.

If this is indeed the case, it requires a special method to reinstall the drivers.

1. Go to your “Control Panel -> System -> Device Manager.”
2. Find your soundcard driver.
3. Right click and choose uninstall.
4. Make sure you check the button: Also remove drivers. If this option is not available, then you didn't select the right sound card.
5. Reboot your PC.
6. Install your soundcard again.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to uninstall every sound card driver one by one in device manager and found the beeping sound to occur regardless.

After uninstalling every driver, i moved USB port my headset was connected too, and naturally the drivers reinstalled with out a reboot and the beeping sound was gone.

I believe the root cause was because I was plugged into a USB 3.0 (Blue) and when moved USB 2.0 the headset functionality was back to normal.

Hope this helps!